# How to center an inline list as the screen gets smaller?

Tags: html, css

I have a nice centered list but as the screen gets smaller, the extra items moves down (this is correct) but they move to the left. I want them centered as when the screen is bigger but I just can't do it.

[image: When the screen is big enough]

I tried two different ways but none of them work as I want.

First I tried with this:

```
.edit-hours .form .inputs .table ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    max-width: 760px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[image: First way as the screen gets smaller]

Then I tried with a flex-box:

```
.edit-hours .form .inputs .table ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    max-width: 760px;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[image: Second way as the screen gets smaller]

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="table">
    <ul>
        <li class="day">
            <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Mon">
            <label for="Mon">Monday</label>
        </li>
        <li class="day">
            <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Tue">
            <label for="Tue">Tuesday</label>
        </li>
        <li class="day">
            <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Wed">
            <label for="Wed">Wednesday</label>
        </li>
        <li class="day">
            <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Thu">
            <label for="Thu">Thursday</label>
        </li>
        <li class="day">
            <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Fri">
            <label for="Fri">Friday</label>
        </li>
        <li class="day">
            <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Sat">
            <label for="Sat">Saturday</label>
        </li>
        <li class="day">
            <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Sun">
            <label for="Sun">Sunday</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would appreciate if somebody could help me!

Comment: Can you post more of your CSS so I can set up a jsFiddle?  Or can you set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: Here you have: https://jsfiddle.net/5gabd607/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post your CSS, but basically you can apply `display: inline` to the `li` elements and center them using `text-align: center` on the `ul` container:

```css
.table ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  max-width: 760px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <ul>
    <li class="day">
      <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Mon">
      <label for="Mon">Monday</label>
    </li>
    <li class="day">
      <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Tue">
      <label for="Tue">Tuesday</label>
    </li>
    <li class="day">
      <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Wed">
      <label for="Wed">Wednesday</label>
    </li>
    <li class="day">
      <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Thu">
      <label for="Thu">Thursday</label>
    </li>
    <li class="day">
      <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Fri">
      <label for="Fri">Friday</label>
    </li>
    <li class="day">
      <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Sat">
      <label for="Sat">Saturday</label>
    </li>
    <li class="day">
      <input class="day-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Sun">
      <label for="Sun">Sunday</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot that, but your answer fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you in your container: `display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap;`

That is it.

```html
<div className="flex justify-center flex-wrap bg-white text-white">
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
  <div className="p-4 m-4 bg-pink-600 rounded-xl">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `className` is JavaScript, `class` is the HTML attribute in which a CSS class-name is added.

Comment: Oh sure, sorry I tested it in my react app.

Comment: Then please either use React in your answer (though it seems unnecessary) or correct your HTML in the answer to be valid; leaving it as it is - without explanation - makes your answer look mistaken. Also remember that comments are ephemeral and subject to deletion, so leaving your comment to 'explain' the use of `className` instead of `class` cannot be relied upon.